# pl/sql procedure not allowing to pass table names/view names as parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I have a small pl/sql procedure that am trying to run in 12c, the code is as follows:

```
create or replace procedure p_ins_tbl(tbl_name in varchar2) as
begin 
execute immediate 'insert into ' ||tbl_name|| 'values(121,''asdfasdf'',6)' ;
end p_ins_tbl;
```

It compiled successfully,

when i tried executing it using: exec `p_ins_tbl(countries);`

Am getting the error as:

```
Error starting at line 6 in command:
exec p_ins_tbl(countries)
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 17:
PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'COUNTRIES' not allowed in this context
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

any reason Y am getting this? Is there any wrong in the procedure if so, please correct me..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a white space before the `values` word, like this: `||tbl_name|| ' values(121,''asdfasdf'',6)'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
execute p_ins_tbl('countries');
```

Comment: `create or replace procedure crt_tbl_rpt(tbl_rpt in varchar2,tbl_cpy in varchar2) is
begin
execute immediate 'create table '||tbl_rpt|| 'as select * from '||tbl_cpy ;
end crt_tbl_rpt;`

is returning me error when I call this procedure as:
`execute crt_tbl_rpt('dept_cpy','departments');`

can u tell me why is it so?
The error is:
`Error report:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at "HR.CRT_TBL_RPT", line 3
ORA-06512: at line 1
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option" `

Comment: `'create table '||tbl_rpt|| 'as select * from '||tbl_cpy ;` wrong, you need a whitespace between `'` and `as`, else it is like `create table dept_cpyas select...` Next time create a new question, I don't want to answer for free.